# SVN, see details while Im committing files

Tags: svn

simple question for svn experts:

Right now Im doing a first commit of a big project (dont need to explain details), and it's like almost 2 Gb of files.

The commit is taking long, and I see the dots moving forward as usual. So my question is if there's a way to show a detailed progress for my commits because I don't know the real progress, how much was already uploaded, and how much is pending.

Thanks

Comment: The commit will finish before you get the answer, so what's the point. And the answer is probably "no".

Comment: 2GB of source? wow.  If such a feature existed, the vast majority of users wouldn't be interested.  most commits are tiny.

Comment: basically I ported a project, and I had to move a lot of folders, remove unused files and reorganize code. So I preferred to remove all svn references and commit all again in a different repository. I know that usually commits are small and takes a short time. But actually I create this post after execute the command and is still committing everything :s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to see more detail with the command line client at current, but you could certainly ask for it by sending an email suggesting this to users@subversion.apache.org.  We actually have the information to print more data (transmission speed and percent done might be tricky, but we could at least provide which file is being transmitted).  If you're not willing to wait for Subversion itself you could modify the client to print whatever you wanted, the notify function isn't terribly complicated.

Unfortunately, David W.'s answer is not really accurate.  The impression that the periods are displayed while the server tries to execute the commit and that the data is already on the server is entirely wrong.  The periods are displayed as each text delta for file contents (which may be full text in some cases) starts being transmitted (as implied by the "Transmitting file data" that is printed just before the periods start).  So the first period will be displayed when the first text is being sent, second after it finishes and the 2nd is about to start and so on.  So if you know how many files you're committing you can get some idea as to how far along it is from this output.

Super technical internal details follow.  The output is implemented in the notify callback function set in the [svn_client_ctx_t](https://people.apache.org/~brane/svndocs/capi/structsvn__client__ctx__t.html) (ctx is short for context).  For a commit you can see this being called from the svn_client__do_commit function as implemented in [subversion/libsvn_client/commit_util.c](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_client/commit_util.c) as follows:

```
  if (ctx->notify_func2)
    {
      svn_wc_notify_t *notify;
      notify = svn_wc_create_notify(item->path,
                                    svn_wc_notify_commit_postfix_txdelta,
                                    iterpool);
      notify->kind = svn_node_file;
      notify->path_prefix = notify_path_prefix;
      ctx->notify_func2(ctx->notify_baton2, notify, iterpool);
    }
```

The event being sent by that code is a [svn_wc_notify_commit_postfix_txdelta](https://people.apache.org/~brane/svndocs/capi/group__svn__wc__notifications.html#gga816dd065327746637bb9af6322959dfba849f0b67e4b6bb9a773a595af7c36a2d), which if you look at the context of that code you'll see is sent just before the text delta is transmitted for a path.

Herein, lies a tiny sliver of truth in David's answer above.  The tree delta has already been transmitted by this point (that means copies, deletes, mkdir, etc have already been sent).  But as the event and the code context implies, the text deltas are delayed to be sent after all of that is finished.  That doesn't particularly help avoid long commits that end up failing because they are out of date, as David points out, but ultimately even if we optimized failures to happen during the delta editor drive we'd still have to check at the point of trying to convert the transaction (that is being built as the edit drive is being done) into a revision for any out of date situations because we don't lock the repository during a transaction (this helps keep Subversion from being less responsive when lots of people are committing).  I believe we have actually tried to make the server return errors sooner, but I haven't dug around in that code much lately so I'm not going to try and make definitive statements about that.

The time spent actually processing the transaction after receiving all the data is relatively small (as by design since we have to take out a write lock on the repo during this processing).  There are two big drains on Subversion commit speeds.  In the case of DAV (http/https) most steps of the delta drive take place in separate HTTP requests (as per the design of DAV and the DeltaV standards).  These requests are executed serially causing round trip delays.  That includes sending file contents.  This contributes greatly to delays when committing lots of small changes over DAV.  You can avoid this issue by using svnserve instead of DAV if this is a common case for you.  In the future we hope to help mitigate some of this with pipelining.  The second issue is that we cannot send text deltas of multiple files in parallel.  This impacts all the various network protocols and at current can't be implemented because the file system implementation for transactions doesn't support it.  We hope to resolve this in the future, switching DAV from neon to serf is a step towards this since serf has more capabilities in this area.

Back to the notify situation.  The notify callback function for the command line client is implemented in [subversion/svn/notify.c](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/notify.c) in a function called notify().  If you search for svn_wc_notify_commit_postfix_txdelta, you'll find this code:

```
case svn_wc_notify_commit_postfix_txdelta:
  if (! nb->sent_first_txdelta)
    {
      nb->sent_first_txdelta = TRUE;
      if ((err = svn_cmdline_printf(pool,
                                    _("Transmitting file data "))))
        goto print_error;
    }

  if ((err = svn_cmdline_printf(pool, ".")))
    goto print_error;
  break;
```

Which is where your periods get printed.  The n argument to the function is a [svn_wc_notify_t](https://people.apache.org/~brane/svndocs/capi/structsvn__wc__notify__t.html) which has all sorts of fields to provide information.  In this case the path, action, kind, and path_prefix should all be set.  So it should be possible to easily display the filename being transmitted with some simple modifications.

Comment: This is a great answer with much technical background! Really appreciated!

Comment: How about on updates? On a slow connection with large files in the repo, not seeing what file is being transmitted is a real hassle. Not to mention rate, time remaining, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: No you can't see the details. At the point you see the periods, your Subversion client has already passed your changes onto the Subversion server. Now, the server is attempting to see if it can commit these changes. At this point, everything is on the server, and the communication between the server and client is limited.

Your Subversion client is like that 1960s expectant sitcom father in the hospital. No one is going to tell him a damn thing until it's over. He simply paces up and down in the waiting room and smoking cigarettes until someone tells him the end result.

Your Subversion client has already passed on the changes to the Subversion server. When you see the periods, it's your Subversion client pacing back and forth until it hears word from the Subversion server what happened (Congratulations! It's a commit!).

Now, the big question: What in the heck are you doing committing 2 Gigabytes worth of files? If there is one file in that big mess of files your committing that can't be committed, your entire commit will be rejected. All of that waiting wasted.

- Commits should be in meaningful bits and pieces. The smaller they are, the faster they are and the less likely that you will end up with a rejected commit. Looking at a fairly large project at my site, all of the source files are a mere 108 megabytes. That's 1/20th of what you have, and this is a fairly large project.
- Don't commit *built artifacts*. Built artifacts are usually very large in size, and they don't version very well because they're usually binary. A tiny change in the source will result in large differences in the built artifact which means it will take up almost that much room with each and every version. My build creates 91Mb of built artifact. If I commit this, it will take up another 91Mb in my Subversion archive. Do this a few dozen times, and I've increased the space my project needs on the Subversion server to over a gigabyte.
   
  Even worse, this binary cannot be diffed to previous versions, so it doesn't help me programmatically, and it goes stale very quickly. A source file I wrote a year ago may still be relevant to my project. But the binary I built a year ago is of no use to anyone.
- One more possibility: You're branching and doing it wrong. There's nothing worse than that. I've beaten developers with a stale muffin to death for that, and I've been acquitted by various juries because they find it completely justifiable.
   
  Do not make a directory, copy your source from the trunk to the branch, do an `svn add` and commit the changes. This makes you lose your entire history on your branch and prevents merging and diffing because, as far as Subversion is concerned, the files on your *branch* are completely different than the files on your *trunk*. You lose the entire purpose of your branch which is to help you understand how it differs from your trunk. Plus, it takes a long, long time because Subversion has to add your entire project once more in your archive.
   
  Do an `svn cp`. Even better, do that using the URL format and not doing a copy into your working directory. That is `svn cp --parents http://server/trunk/project http://server/branch/1.2/project`. This keeps your history intact, and Subversion will create the branch almost immediately.

By now, your commit is probably complete. You've either been told that your commit happened, or it was rejected and you've wasted 20 to 40 minutes watching that little period printing out over and over again. Next time, don't try such large commits. Break it up. Don't commit built artifacts. If you need a built artifact, you can rebuild it. (You can also store them for other projects in a Release Repository which isn't under Subversion control.)

Comment: I've explained on the other comment, anyway I copypaste my answer about the 2Gb project: "basically I ported a project, and I had to move a lot of folders, remove unused files and reorganize code. So I preferred to remove all svn references and commit all again in a different repository". Regarding the big files, there are files from art that need to be on the repository, I think that's the worst part.  Thanks for you response!

Comment: Unfortunately David's comments about when those periods are printed isn't accurate here.  See my answer for the details since it's too long to fit as a comment.

Comment: @Rod.C I've always seen the individual messages `Sending <filename>` and assumed that's when the file was sent. Others have told me that the main purpose of the periods was to let the user know something was going on, so they won't think SVN client had frozen. Since I've done similar things as a programmer, it made sense. Thanks for the clarification. Does the client know in advance the number of deltas sent? Then you could have a client message `Delta X or Y sent`. It would give the user a better idea how long a commit might take.

Comment: Think that response is directed at me.  But yes the client should be able to calculate how many deltas it has to send (client might not know it since it may just depend on the library to figure that out for it) and it also is notified with the specific filename before it starts sending the delta.  I think some of your confusion is from the fact that fairly early in SVN development it was changed to allow deltas to be sent at the end of the editor drive which meant they weren't sent when the Sending message is displayed.  See my answer above for details.

Comment: @BenReser That could be that I was confused by earlier revisions. I have been using SVN since rev 1.1. I was spec'ing out a job and decided to give that _new_ version control system a shot instead of using time proven CVS.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little investigation into this, I did a big commit (1060 files) and at the end I examined the output. I found that the number of dots matched the number of files exactly (Including Adding, Deleting, and Sending files).

This was done on a mac, but it can probably be done on any *nix and probably be done on windows running cygwin or similar.

The way I tested was after "Transmitting file data" phase began, copy/paste that into a temp file and then perform a `wc -l your_file` and that will give you total files being committed.

Then to calculate the progress copy the dots and `echo "PASTE_DOTS_HERE" | wc -c` to get files processed so far, then divide by the total files and multiply by 100and that should give you a rough idea of progress percentage.

Keep in mind that files of different sized will take longer to send and process so the dots don't all take the same time to appear.

Hope that helps someone.